# Firefox Extension Developement how to debug preferences page?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

How do I debug, like console.log(); the Preferences Page of the Extension? Thanks

Comment: I am pretty sure that this is done through Error Console under Firefox->Tools->Error Console, Though it gives me error - console.log is not defined =(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to debug with Firebug, using `Firebug.Console.log()`.

Answer (score 0):

I would just use [`window.dump`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.dump). If you really want the Firebug console, you could probably get a reference to main browser window using:

```
var mainWindow = window.QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIInterfaceRequestor)
               .getInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIWebNavigation)
               .QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIDocShellTreeItem)
               .rootTreeItem
               .QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIInterfaceRequestor)
               .getInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIDOMWindow);
```

([from here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Working_with_windows_in_chrome_code)) and then call `mainWindow.console.log`. Haven't tried it, but I think it should work.